# Why is libman.json created with Build Action set to "Content" and Copy to Output Directory set to "Copy if newer?"

Tags: visual-studio, build, publish, libman

**Context**

When I use Add Client Side Library in VS it creates the `libman.json` file in the project with the Build Action set to "Content" and the Copy to Output Directory set to "Copy if newer."

**Question**

Why is libman.json created with those properties set to those values? As far I understand, both are obsolete because the only thing we must pay attention to is that `libman.json` should be put in source control. What am I missing?

**(Optional reading)**

In a scenario with multiple projects, there could be multiple `libman.json` files, so the **Copy if newer** setting makes the build process override other `libman.json` files with the last one added, and the **Content** setting makes the publish process override other `libman.json` files with the last one as well (or fail in .NET 6, but this post is not about how to workaround that).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer (at least, in SDK-style .NET projects) is that it's coming from the SDK's file globbing patterns, most probably from the Razor SDK ([here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/dcaf73c6398fd50d72dc36da2407a7937cc7360b/src/RazorSdk/Sdk/Sdk.Razor.StaticAssets.ProjectSystem.props#L28)).

You'll get the same issue with any other file, such as a package.json file, including the same errors in the multiple-project scenario with duplicate file names.

Comment: So.. should we stop copying it to the publishing folder?